# (Unity)Game view and smartphone view are different

Tags: unity-game-engine, aspect

In the game view, it appears horizontally as expected, but in the smartphone view, it appears vertically. I do not know what is the problem. How to fix?(My smartphone has 1080 x 2400 pixels, 20:9 ratio screen)

[Unity game view]
[image]

[My smartphone]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Setting the orientation to landscape only](https://answers.unity.com/questions/774186/landscape-mode-only.html) should work